# ¿Como haria para que tambien ponga los input en esta caja de texto?

Tags: python, tkinter, input

bueno primero antes de empezar utilizo python 3.10 y como IDE utilizo vsc(visual estudio code) nesecito que cada ves que salga un input lo reconosca esta es mi ventana en mi codigo es una ventana secundaria o ventana hijo:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk


class StdOutRedirect:
    def __init__(self,  text: tk.Text) -> None:
     self._text = text

    def write(self,  out: str) -> None:
     self._text.insert(tk.END,  out)


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.stdout_text = tk.Text(
         self,  bg="black",  fg="#38B179",  font=("Helvetica", 15))
        self.stdout_text.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        sys.stdout = StdOutRedirect(self.stdout_text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Toplevel()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    print("Hola mundo")
    print("Hola Juan")
    print("StackOverflow")
```

esta ventana imprime en una ventana todo lo que se le pase pero ahora tambien quiero agregarle que tambien haga input me podrian hechar una mano en esto?, en todo caso que no se pueda lo podrian hacer en un ventana aparte. Ayudenme por favor

Comment: Redirecciona a sys.stdin

Comment: @DanteS. ok he estado viendo si podria ser pero no podras responder como hiria en el codigo por favor

Comment: Me da miedo de hacer lo que buscas por ti sin que te hayas esforzado. Prefiero que primero investigues un poco y lo intentes. Luego agrega ese intento a la pregunta (incluso si no funciona). Recien ahí podría considerar responderte con código.

Comment: sys.stdin es como un archivo de texto abierto en modo lectura. El método read supongo que también captura el input.

Comment: @DanteS. bueno lo unico que he podido hacer es usar esta codigo: pyautogui.prompt(text, titulo, lo que quieras poner dentro de la caja de texto)